# Good, idiomatic way to refactor out business logic from controllers

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am new to Scala and Play; and I wrote a "do all" controller that contains both business and presentation logic. I want to refactor the business logic out of the controller.

Here's what my Scala/Play looks like. What is a good/idiomatic way to refactor out the business logic out of this controller, with a clean interface?

```
object NodeRender extends Controller {
...
def deleteNode(nodeId: Long) = Action { request =>
    //business logic
    val commitDocument = Json.toJson(
    Map(
        "delete" -> Seq( Map( "id" -> toJson( nodeId)))  
    ))
    val commitSend   = Json.stringify( commitDocument)
    val commitParams = Map( "commit" -> "true", "wt" -> "json")
    val headers = Map( "Content-type" -> "application/json")

    val sol = host( "127.0.0.1", 8080)
    val updateReq  = sol / "solr-store" / "collection1" / "update" / "json" <<?
        commitParams <:< headers << commitSend

    val commitResponse = Http( updateReq)()

    //presentation logic
    Redirect( routes.NodeRender.listNodes)
}
```

---

In Python/Django I write two classes `XApiHandler` and `XBackend` and use a clean interface between them.

```
xb = XBackend( user).do_stuff()
if not xb:
  return a_404_error
else:
  return the_right_stuff( xb.content) #please dont assume its a view!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few assumptions:

1) The HTTP call on your second last line blocks

2) You don't say whether the redirect needs to wait for the response from the Http call, but I assume it does.

Blocking call should be moved to another thread so that you aren't blocking threads that handle requests.  Play docs are quite specific about this.  The `Akka.future` function combined with `Async`helps.

Controller code:

```
1 def deleteNode(nodeId: Long) = Action { request =>
2     Async{
3         val response = Akka.future( BusinessService.businessLogic(nodeId) )
4 
5         response.map { result =>
6             result map {
7                 Redirect( routes.NodeRender.listNodes)
8             } recover {
9                 InternalServerError("Failed due to ...")
10            } get 
11        }
12    }
13}
```

This is a bit more than your PHP, but it is multi-threaded.

The code passed to `Akka.future` on line 3 will be called at some time in the future using a different thread.  But the call to `Akka.future` returns immediately with a `Future[Try]` (see below for the return type of the business method).  That means the variable `response` has the type `Future[Try]`.  The call to the `map` method on line 5 doesn't call the code inside the map block, rather it registers that code (lines 6-10) as a callback.  The thread doesn't block on line 5 and returns the `Future` to the `Async` block.  The `Async` block returns a `AsyncResult` to Play and that tells Play to register itself for a callback when the future is completed.

In the mean time, some other thread will make the call to the `BusinessService` from line 3 and once the HTTP call that you make to the back end system returns, the `response` variable on line 3 is "completed" meaning that the callback on lines 6-10 gets called.  `result` has the type `Try` which is abstract and has just two subclasses: `Success` and `Failure`.  If `result` is a sucess, then the `map` method calls line 7 and wraps it in a new `Success`.  If `result` is a failure, then the map method returns the failure.  The `recover` method on line 8 does the opposite.  If the result of the map method is a success, then it returns the success, otherwise it calls line 9 and wraps it in a `Success` (not a `Failure`!).  The call to the `get` method on line 10 takes the redirect or the error out of the `Success` and that value is used to complete the `AsyncResult` which Play is holding on to.  Play then gets a callback that the response is ready and can be rendered and sent.

Using this solution, no threads which service incoming requests get blocked.  That's important because for example on a 4 core machine, Play only has 8 threads capable of handling incoming requests.  It won't spawn any new ones, at least not when using the default configuration.

Here is the code from the Business Service object (pretty much copied your code):

```
def businessLogic(nodeId: Long): Future[Try] {

    val commitDocument = Json.toJson(
    Map(
       "delete" -> Seq( Map( "id" -> toJson( nodeId)))  
    ))
    val commitSend   = Json.stringify( commitDocument)
    val commitParams = Map( "commit" -> "true", "wt" -> "json")
    val headers = Map( "Content-type" -> "application/json")

    val sol = host( "127.0.0.1", 8080)
    val updateReq  = sol / "solr-store" / "collection1" / "update" / "json" <<?
        commitParams <:< headers << commitSend

    val commitResponse = Http( updateReq)()

    Success(commitResponse) //return the response or null, doesnt really matter so long as its wrapped in a successful Try 
}
```

The presentation logic and the business logic are now totally decoupled.

See https://speakerdeck.com/heathermiller/futures-and-promises-in-scala-2-dot-10 and http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html for more information.

Comment: How would you test the `deleteNode` action?

Comment: Good question!  I guess "BusinessService" shouldn't be an object, then it can be mocked and you can do a test for a positive and a negative result.  See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTest for more details.  Or do you mean specifically that different parts run in different threads?

Comment: Also, Akka.future relies on an instance of the Play application, which can be stubbed for unit testing like this: implicit val application = Application(new File("."), this.getClass.getClassloader, None, Play.Mode.Dev)

Comment: How would you inject a mock instance into the `deleteNode` action?

Comment: `FakeApplication` is a bit easier to use for mocking the `Application`

Comment: How about this: def deleteNode(nodeId: Long)(
    implicit nodeService: NodeService = NodeService)...

Comment: @AntKutschera your answer goes above and beyond what I asked! For example, the "no threads which service incoming requests get blocked"

Answer (score 4):

I would probably do it like this

```
object NodeRenderer extends Controller {

  def listNodes = Action { request =>
    Ok("list")
  }

  def deleteNode(nodeId: Long)(
    implicit nodeService: NodeService = NodeService) = Action { request =>

    Async {
      Future {
        val response = nodeService.deleteNode(nodeId)

        response.apply.fold(
          error => BadRequest(error.message),
          success => Redirect(routes.NodeRenderer.listNodes))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The node service file would look something like this

```
trait NodeService {
  def deleteNode(nodeId: Long): Promise[Either[Error, Success]]
}

object NodeService extends NodeService {

  val deleteDocument =
    (__ \ "delete").write(
      Writes.seq(
        (__ \ "id").write[Long]))

  val commitParams = Map("commit" -> "true", "wt" -> "json")
  val headers = Map("Content-type" -> "application/json")

  def sol = host("127.0.0.1", 8080)
  def baseReq = sol / "solr-store" / "collection1" / "update" / "json" <<?
    commitParams <:< headers

  def deleteNode(nodeId: Long): Promise[Either[Error, Success]] = {

    //business logic
    val commitDocument =
      deleteDocument
        .writes(Seq(nodeId))
        .toString

    val updateReq = baseReq << commitDocument

    Http(updateReq).either.map(
      _.left.map(e => Error(e.getMessage))
        .right.map(r => Success))
  }
}
```

Where I defined `Error` and `Success` like this

```
case class Error(message: String)
trait Success
case object Success extends Success
```

This separates your http part and business logic, allowing you to create other types of front-ends for the same service. At the same time it allows you to test your http handling while supplying a mock of the `NodeService`.

If you need to have different types of `NodeService` bound to the same controller you might convert the `NodeRenderer` to a class and pass it in using the constructor. [This example](https://github.com/guillaumebort/play20-spring-demo) shows you how to do that.

Comment: I only added some stuff to make it useful. I moved the static parts to the service so they can be reused by other methods. I added some extra code to give the OP more options for his implementation. I also have the habit of spreading things over more lines to make things more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I'm pretty happy with factoring out coherent logic blocks into mix-in traits.

```
abstract class CommonBase {
    def deleteNode(): Unit
}


trait Logic extends CommonBase{
  this: NodeRender =>

  override def deleteNode(): Unit = {
    println("Logic Here")
    println(CoolString)
    }
}

class NodeRender extends CommonBase
    with Logic
{
    val CoolString = "Hello World"

}



object test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("starting ...")
      (new NodeRender()).deleteNode()
    }
}
```

prints

```
starting ...
Logic Here
Hello World
```